# Is a ':methods' option in 'to_json' substitutable with an ':only' option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

The `to_json` option has options `:only` and `:methods`. The former is intended to accept attributes and the latter methods.

I have a model that has an attribute `foo`, which is overwritten:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def foo
    # Overrides the original attribute `foo`
    "the overwritten foo value"
  end
end
```

The overwritten `foo` method seems to be called irrespective of which option I write the `foo` under.

```
SomeModel.first.to_json(only: [:foo])
# => "{..., \"foo\":\"the overwritten foo value\", ...}"

SomeModel.first.to_json(methods: [:foo])
# => "{..., \"foo\":\"the overwritten foo value\", ...}"
```

This seems to suggest it does not matter whether I use `:only` or `:methods`.

Is this the case? I feel something wrong with my thinking.

---

The source code leads to these:

**File activemodel/lib/active_model/serialization.rb, line 124**

```
def serializable_hash(options = nil)
  options ||= {}

  attribute_names = attributes.keys
  if only = options[:only]
    attribute_names &= Array(only).map(&:to_s)
  elsif except = options[:except]
    attribute_names -= Array(except).map(&:to_s)
  end

  hash = {}
  attribute_names.each { |n| hash[n] = read_attribute_for_serialization(n) }

  Array(options[:methods]).each { |m| hash[m.to_s] = send(m) }

  serializable_add_includes(options) do |association, records, opts|
    hash[association.to_s] = if records.respond_to?(:to_ary)
      records.to_ary.map { |a| a.serializable_hash(opts) }
    else
      records.serializable_hash(opts)
    end
  end

  hash
end
```

**File activeresource/lib/active_resource/base.rb, line 1394**

```
def read_attribute_for_serialization(n)
  attributes[n]
end
```

and it seems that an `:only` option calls `attributes[n]` and `:methods` option calls `send(m)`. What is the difference?